# When to_json is *almost* good enough

Tags: ruby, json, rabl

I'm rendering json for a view in a Rails app for a model object with several levels of nested child objects.  Initially, to_json was good enough as I didn't have a need to add/modify/rename anything from the model object.  However, I now need to insert some URIs in the json (for some of the nested child objects) that aren't in the model objects.  I'm looking at using RABL but from what I've seen so far it looks like I'll need to specify a lot more of the formatting for objects that I still want the default to_json behavior on, just to be able to get to the point where I can add the URIs on some of the child objects.  What I *think* I want is a way to use to_json on a graph of objects and be able to specify that only objects of a certain type need to be handled differently.  Has anyone done something similar with RABL or know of a better approach altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can override as_json in the model, so as to add extra things.

For example

```
def some_url
    "http://google.com"
end



def as_json(options={})
    options = User.json_options(options)
    super(options)
end

def self.json_options(options = {})
    options ||= {} # need this because to_json without options will pass nil to as_json
    options[:methods] ||= []
    options[:methods] << :some_url
    options
end
```

THen when you call to_json the method will be included.